# How to read Pillow image to cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to do this without saving `bw`to avoid having to read the file every time I save, and transform it directly so that it can be read with opencv.

```
#Image Pillow open
img = Image.open('/content/drive/My Drive/TESTING/Placas_detectadas/HCPD24.png')
gray = img.convert('L')
bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<80 else 255, '1')
bw.save('xd.png')

#Imagen from opencv
im = cv2.imread('/content/xd.png')
im = ~im
cv2_imshow(im)
cv2.imwrite('wena.png',im)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could do the same transformation with OpenCV alone, if that's fine for your use case...

Comment: How it could be? I tried before with no success

Comment: You can convert the image directly to greyscale during reading, and save 66% memory and a line of code if you use `im = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Comment: Thanks! good advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to transform the image into grayscale, then mask it so everything less bright than 80 is white, and everything above that is black, you can do it all rather quickly in OpenCV:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Grayscale image
_, im = cv2.threshold(im, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # Threshold at brightness 80 and invert
cv2.imwrite('converted.png', im)  # Write output
```